# getting error file format incorrect, reading file in c

Tags: c, feof

if i run 1 data, program execution is success. but in 2 data format file incorrect. where did i go wrong?

File .txt

```
1,Nanggroe Aceh Darussalam,Rumah Sakit,RSU Cut Nyak Dhien,Jl. Tm Bahrum No. 1 Langsa
2,Jawa Barat,Klinik Utama,dr. Sunarhadi,Raya Cikaret No. 12
```

Read code

```
do{
    read = fscanf(file,
                    "%d,%100[^,],%100[^,],%100[^,],%100[^,]\n",          
                    &students[records].no, 
                    students[records].prov, 
                    students[records].tipe, 
                    students[records].nama,
                    students[records].alamat); 

    if (read == 5) records++;
    
    if (read != 5 && !feof(file)){
      printf("File format incorrect.\n");
      return 1;
    }
    
    if (ferror(file)){
      printf("Error reading file.\n");
      return 1;
    }

  } while (!feof(file));
```

Output says

```
File format incorrect.
```

How can i output like

```
No      : 1
Prov    : Nanggroe Aceh Darussalam
Tipe    : Rumah Sakit
Nama    : RSU Cut Nyak Dhien
Alamat  : Jl. Tm Bahrum No. 1 Langsa

No      : 2
Prov    : Jawa Barat
Tipe    : Klinik Utama
Nama    : dr. Sunarhadi
Alamat  : Raya Cikaret No. 12
```

Comment: Parsing lines with `scanf`-like functions is a recipe for disaster. Use `fgets` to get a line, then use whatever to parse that line, you could use `sscanf` if you like.

Comment: xNapzm , please post the definition of   `students` and its `struct`.

Comment: @DevSolar, the use of `feof()` is not the problem here, and in fact is correct in an obscure fashion.  Problem is in `"...%100[^,]\n"`.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Sometimes I push my trigger too fast. Didn't see the `feof()` in the middle of the loop. Thanks for reopening.

Comment: Note that error messages should be written to `stderr` and not `stdout`.

Answer (score 3):

The format is incorrect. It expects a *trailing* comma on the lines.

Change:

```
"%d,%100[^,],%100[^,],%100[^,],%100[^,]\n"
```

Into:

```
"%d,%100[^,],%100[^,],%100[^,],%100[^\n]\n"
```

---

Notes:

1. Never use `feof`. Just check the return value of `fscanf` and ensure it's equal to 5. See: [Why is “while( !feof(file) )” always wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feoffile-always-wrong)
2. You check `ferror` but never show what `errno` is in your `printf`

Comment: And be wary of [trailing white space in `scanf()` format strings](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19499060/15168).  Here, where the data comes from a file, it is probably not a problem unless someone is careless enough to provide `/dev/tty` as the file name instead of `file.txt`, but in general, it is a bad idea.